# Push notification from app using parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push

i am using parse 1.13.0 in nodechef.com i tried setting my app to send notification but i getting some problems.

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.my.path" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.my.path.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.my.path.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/hsfTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
        android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/logo" />

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.my.path" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- activity main. -->
    <activity
        android:name=".A0"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation"
        android:immersive="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/hsfTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".A1" />
    <activity android:name=".A2" />
    <activity android:name=".A3" />
    <activity android:name=".utils.A4" />

    <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>
```

in my application class i have: ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

- DeviceToken is empty in _Installation class
- Push not working

All i need is send push notification from my app, in some actions i would like notify all users or some users using Installation channels. Don't care if i will use "parse push" or gcm, just need a simple way to send push notifications from app.

**EDIT**
Push from parse-dashboard is working now, but i cant send push notification from client. I tried a push and got "unauthorized: enable master key". So what i need to do ?

**EDIT 2**
I created a cloud code but its looks not working get values from **request.params**:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendPush", function(request,response) {
var _locale = "en-US";//request.params.locale;
var _message = "test";//request.params.message;
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo("localeIdentifier", _locale);
Parse.Push.send({
        data:   {
            alert: _message,
        badge: "Increment",
            sound: "default"
        },
        where: query
    }, {
      useMasterKey: true
    })
    .then(function() {
      response.success("Push Sent!");
    }, function(error) {
      response.error("Error while trying to send push " + error.message);
    });
});
```

**EDIT 3**

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("locale","en-US");
map.put("message","Text added");

ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendPush",map, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {

    @Override
    public void done(Object object, ParseException e) {
        // toast done
    }
});
```

Comment: what is the problem? can you please share more code?

Comment: @RanHassid i added more information about the problem.

Comment: you use parse.com or parse-server?

Comment: i use nodechef.com with parse-server

Comment: and did you follow this guide here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push

Comment: I tried some examples to like this but i didn't followed this tutorial. I will try at night. If its work i will let you know. tks atm.

Comment: Hi Ran, now parse is saving devicetoken and i can send notification from server. So, what i can do to send notifications from app ?

I am using the code: 

ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
                        query.whereStartsWith(ParseIdentify.fieldLocale, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());

String textAdded = "Title ["+ textFinal +"] added!";
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(query);
push.setMessage(textAdded);
push.sendInBackground();

Comment: yes, it should work.

Comment: Now i having problems with client push unauthorized. So i will need find a way to turn on this on parse (client push) or i will need configure a instance to run parse cloud code.

Comment: there is a reason why you are getting that.. i describe it in the answer

Comment: can you please add also you android code where you are calling this function/

Comment: Sure, tjs again.

I added on post.

Comment: It looks like the request.params is undefined means that from some reason the cloud code ignore the parameters that are being sent by android SDK. i will continue to investigate it.

Comment: Hi, I tested it again and it works on my side. Which parse-server version you are using?

Comment: 2.2.17 but i can change it easily, so what version worked to you ? i will try change here

Comment: i tried version 2.2.16 and its looks ok :) i will publish to test. thanks for your help Ran. I will let you know if everything work ok after publish

Comment: its working with 2.2.16. Something is wrong with 2.2.17.

Comment: Hi, for me it works also in 2.2.17... it's really strange.

Answer (score 1):

after investigate it a bit i noticed that in order to send push you must create cloud code function and use your master key (by sending **userMasterKey=true**  parameter to the send push function. 
I describe my answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38739398/4287861) so please go through the steps and it should work for you.

Comment: Tks Ran, i found CLI tool. But i would like to know how to deploy your script (i never did it before and i am worried about crash default settings).

Comment: When you deploy parse-server it also deploy your cloud code script. the cloud code script should be located under the cloud folder there you can create all the cloud code functions

Comment: So i will need get all my code before deploy, right ? well, i need read about node js to learn hot to deploy, download source, etc...

Comment: In parse-server docs you can find how to deploy parse-server to different cloud providers such as: AWS, google cloud, heroku and more. go to this link: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server and read the instructions under "Running Parse Server elsewhere"

Comment: Ran, i edited question again, can you check and try help me again ?