# Parse Push Notification Exception: "unauthorized: master key is required"

Tags: android, parse-platform, push

I want to send push Notification using Parse API and GCM. I have done successfully configuration on server and test via sending push notification form Parse terminal and receive at android device.

But when i'm sending push programmatically then got an Exception: **"unauthorized: master key is required"**.

I using following code:

```
ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("channels", "testing");

    // Notification for Android users
    query.whereEqualTo("deviceType", "android");
    ParsePush androidPush = new ParsePush();
    androidPush.setMessage("Your suitcase has been filled with tiny robots!");
    androidPush.setQuery(query);
    androidPush.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if ( e == null ) {
                Log.d("GARG","Parse Notification Done. : ");
            } else {
                Log.d("GARG","Notification failed.: "+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

android manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.demo">

<permission
    android:name="com.demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".AppInitializer"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_cast_light" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
        android:value="id:211671060483" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
        android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.X-Parse-Master-Key"
        android:value="@string/parse_master_key" />

<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />


            <category android:name="com.demo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Initialize Parse SDK in android

```
public class AppInitializer extends Application {

public static JSONObject errorDataProvider;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId(Utility.ApplicationId)
            .clientKey(Utility.ClientKey)
            .server(Utility.Server_URL)
            .build()
    );

    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(Utility.PARSE_CHANNEL, new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            Log.e("GARG", "Successfully subscribed to Parse!");
        }
    });
    }
 }
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/back4app/AbWfQSRjsAU

Comment: Hi @IntelliJ Amiya i have set master key there but facing same exception

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya have you any idea about any uses of Master_Key in android code. means what we need to set Master_key in android app like Application_id and client_key

Comment: No sorry for that .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Hi, i investigate it a bit and found that currently the only to send Push is by using the **masterKey**  and that's exactly the reason why you are getting this error

In order to send push with master key the best approach will be to create a cloud code function and trigger this function from the client side. 
so you need to do the following:

1. Inside your cloud code main.js file create a new function

```js
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("SendPush", function(request) {


  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  query.exists("deviceToken");

  // here you can add other conditions e.g. to send a push to sepcific users or channel etc.

  var payload = {
    alert: "YOUR_MESSAGE"
      // you can add other stuff here...
  };


  Parse.Push.send({
      data: payload,
      where: query
    }, {
      useMasterKey: true
    })
    .then(function() {
      response.success("Push Sent!");
    }, function(error) {
      response.error("Error while trying to send push " + error.message);
    });
});
```

**After you created the cloud code function restart your server**

2. Trigger this cloud code function from your android app in the following way:

   ```
   HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
   map.put("PARAM1KEY","PARAM1VALUE");
   // here you can send parameters to your cloud code functions
   // such parameters can be the channel name, array of users to send a push to and more...

   ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("SendPush",map, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {

       @Override
       public void done(Object object, ParseException e) {
           // handle callback 
       }
   });
   ```

This will trigger a call to the cloud code function that you created above and inside the cloud code the **useMasterKey** is **true** so it should work.

update: spelling

Comment: What about the master key ? Did you also specify the master key?

Comment: yeah i have configure masterkey in index.js

Comment: Have you any idea about any uses of Master_Key in android code. means what we need to set Master_key in android app like Application_id and client_key

Comment: Will check it out later soon as I will be next to computer and will edit the answer ...

Comment: Ok @Ran Hassid I'm waiting for answer

Comment: @Greg's can you please paste the code where you initialize the Parse SDK

Comment: Hi @Garg's i updated the answer. Please do all the steps that i described in my  answer and it will work.

Comment: Cloud code is good for pre-defined push queries, but I think the question was trying to build them dynamically from the Android API

Comment: You can build them dynamically also in cloud code. Just send the relevant parameters to your cloud code function and build it there. It's even much better because you write the push query once and then it can be consumed by any technology (ios,android,web etc.)

Comment: @Ran Hassid hii i have try this code but getting an exception : com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: Invalid function.

Comment: After you have added it to your cloud code you restart the server?

Comment: can you please add some code. your cloud code and how you call it from android?

Comment: What did you do after you restarted your server?

Comment: I just added "useMasterKey: true" and work for me.. Thanks for great full help

Answer (score 0):

> useMasterKey: true

that will enable parse server to use master key to push notification from client side.