# Parse push notification still going to stop on January 28, 2017?

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

I  have an application which is hosted on Amazon (AWS) server and an app admin on godaddy.in admin. I can send push  notification using parse server API (https://api.parse.com/1/push') to app user.

My question is:

1. Is parse server push notification also going to stop by 28 Jan 2017?
2. Can I send particular user push notification using parse server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the answer to your questions are:

1. Yes push notifications will also not going to work since the push is done through the parse.com server which will not be available. so parse.com with all of its services will not be available.
2. Sure you can. The current limitation is that when you send push with parse-server you must **use your master key** so in order to do it you need to create a cloud code function and from there to write the code that handle the push notifications. I already gave an answer on how it can be done .. you can read the detailed answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38739398/4287861)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are yet to migrate your app from parse to your own self hosted environment. More details available [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-Server)

After you might have done that, visit the [Push Wiki](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-Server/wiki/Push) page on how you can configure your push notification. It's a fairly easy process.